# how to be a professional asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry for ask a question like this.
But I really want to improve my programming skill on asp.net mvc.
I can build only sample asp.net mvc (model,view,controller) but really dont know how to make it as enterprise web.
I see a few projects on google they build mvc with professional way (NHibernate,Log4net,Mapping....) and split to a few projects in a solution (Data,Common,Test,Api...)

My question is how can I start to be professional like them. Give me some idea or link to start.

Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Videos and tutorials are all right, but you won't really learn until you try to do something. Just decide to do something. It doesn't have to be something great, you can start developing a classified ads site. As long as you take the task from a professional point of view.

Then, you'll start finding challenges to overcome and you'll start searching for the answers you need. Real life challenges. Tutorials are great, but sometimes they are better for consulting on demand than for reading from cover to cover.

JUST DO IT

Comment: It seem great idea i will follow do it from small to big

Answer (score 0):

Pluralsight has some excellent videos, as does Lynda.com

I would start with Youtube.

Working with MVC, in my experience, means that your javascript has to be up to snuff as does your .NET language of choice.

Comment: I always watch on youtube to detail about part i need to learn ex: how to use NHibernate...
But I wonder why another project on google they know how to split project to easy maintain thier (Web , Common , Data ....)
Where can I get those ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Do you mean how to properly segment the data, like a design pattern? If so, you should spend some time reading about various design patterns.

Comment: Yeah yeah u right. Sometime i dunno technical word :)
Can u suggest some book or any link me to learn ? 
Thanks.